# Chainring for 1x8 drivetrain

Tags: chainring, drivetrain

I'm building a city/light-touring bike with a single chainring and an 8 speed cassette (11-32T). I bought cranks with the wrong chainring; one for single speed, with a 1/8" chain. I now want to make sure I get the correct chainring. I'm looking for around 44-46 teeth. I'm having some trouble finding one that's not too expensive. I'm looking at this one:

https://specialites-ta.com/plateaux/road/single-chainring.html

It says "Compatible with 7, 8, 9 and 10 speed chains", which I assume is 3/32" chains (what I have), but I'm thinking it might not work well with the lateral movement of the chain from the rear derailleur, as they don't mention derailleurs at all: "Chainring for single use, such as tandem, Rohloff, single speed, urban fittings ...". Can anyone shed some light on this, or what I should look for in a chainring for this use case? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The chainring did not work well. Even though the chain fitted on the teeth of the chainring, it did not handle the lateral movement of the chain well when shifting. It like the chain sat too deep on the chainring to allow lateral movement. I ordered a chainring made for a front setup with multiple chainrings.

Comment: That seems surprising.  What do you mean by didn't handle?  Did it fall off? Rattle annoyingly?

Comment: Rattle annoyingly

Comment: I *hope* the replacement will be better.  I'm not sure it will be.

Comment: The replacement seems to work quite well. I need to try it out in the field to see if the chain doesn't drop off on rough roads but shifting works beautifully. I got this one, the inner version with 44 teeth:
https://specialites-ta.com/plateaux/road/alize-chainring.html

Answer (score 2):

If it specifically calls out that it's compatible with 7, 8, 9 and 10-speed chains, I have to assume it would also be compatible with those systems.  That link resolves to a "404 item not found" on my end, don't know if it's a regional thing or what, so I couldn't look at it myself in this case.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Order it, I'll post back here if it works.